# Load Bitmap on BaseAdapter

Tags: android, bitmap, getresource

Hi I want to load **resource drawable in bitmap type at baseadapter** but get some **error**

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.messenger);
```

the `getResource()` need to make function on the java file.

how to get it?

Comment: Post your code properly and clear your question with more details.

Comment: Did you tried my answer ? @Aladi Renaldi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass your activity instance to the Base adapter first , then change you function to

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(activity.getResources(), R.drawable.messenger);
```

Answer (score 0):

to create BaseAdapter must need Context, almost from Activity, getResources() is contain context.

modify to it

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(), R.drawable.messenger);
```

i hope it helped.